# processing the google visualization query response not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I want to query a spreadsheet sheet and see if the dataset returned is empty using the google visualization API system, but my code is not working (the alert box with the message "The query did not return any rows") does not pop up. I made the query url to search for data that is not in the spreadsheet so that I do get an empty dataset, just to test out my code.

**Code:**

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['table', 'map', 'corechart']});
         google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
         
           function initialize() {
             // The URL of the spreadsheet to source data from.
             var query = new google.visualization.Query(
                 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u4eLf6abU57PJcE8bWxxs-e9g-mOYHJs2KryZ7BOPs0/gviz/tq?sheet=Volunteer&tq=select+*+where+A=""');
                 

             query.send(processResponse);
           }
         
           function processResponse(response) {
             if (response.isError()) {

              alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());

             }
         else{
             var data = response.getDataTable();
             
             if (data == null) {

                  alert('The query did not return any rows');
               }

           }
             
             
           }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      This is just a test page.
   </body>
</html>
```

The alert box with the message "The query did not return any rows" does not pop up. Nothing happens on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the condition against the number of rows:

```
data.getNumberOfRows()
```

if its cero it means the query did not return any rows.

You can find more info about the DataTable object and its methods [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable).
Hope this helps.